# auto-complete search suggestion drop-down popup

Tags: javascript, jsp, html, autocomplete, popup

Im trying to make a popup div (when a text-box value changes) and it can be closed (visibility: none) by clicking anywhere outside the div.
Similar to Google suggestion drop-down.

How can I know weather the mouse click has happened inside the div or outside.

I need to implement this using javascript and jsp.

Please help.

Comment: This question may be relevant (for finding words in an array that are similar to a search query): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377096/find-similar-words-in-array-of-words

Comment: Also, here are some more relevant questions (for finding similar words): http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+levenshtein+distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jquery solution would be

```
$("body > div").click(function() {
if ($(this).attr("id") == "div-id") {
    // inside the DIV
} else {
    // not inside the DIV
}
});
```

or

```
$("html").click(function (e)
{
if (e.target == document.getElementById("div-id"))
    alert("Inside DIV");
else
    alert("Outside DIV!");
});
```

or Javascript snippet would be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.onclick=check; 
function check(e){ 
var target = (e && e.target) || (event && event.srcElement); 
var obj = document.getElementById('div-id'); 
if(target!=obj){obj.style.display='none'} 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: can you please explain me this line "var target = (e && e.target) || (event && event.srcElement);"

Comment: Function `check` will be called when the document is clicked anywhere, and passed the `click` event. That line checks if the event is indeed passed as an argument to the function (in most browsers), or if not (other browsers, probably IE), tries to grab the event from the global variable `event`.

Comment: Writing pure javascript is usually cumbersome because one has to write different code like that to make it work in all browsers correctly. If one uses jQuery though, all that is taken care of behind the curtains, so you won't have to worry about forgetting to handle a specific browser.

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to popup a div behind that covers the whole screen (invisible), and capture clicks on that div to close both popup divs.  You could also try capturing clicks on the `body` tag and that should catch clicks anywhere outside the div (or inside the div as well if events bubble - you may want to perform some testing).

Sometimes an easier method is to use a timeout, like popup CSS menus that disappear once your mouse has been off of the menu for a couple of seconds.  You can catch the `onmouseleave` event, start a timer, and as long as there isn't another `onmouseenter` in say, two seconds, then hide the popup div.

Hope this helps!

Comment: one question. since the background div covers the whole screen, then clicking on the popup div also would cause the div's to close.   please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @kanap008: Not if the click event is not bubbled.  You can use `window.event.cancelBubble = true;` to stop the event going through to both divs.  See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: which is what jQuery's `e.stopPropagation()` does behind the curtains.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with jQuery. If you click on the "test" text, you make the other text appear. Clicking anywhere else except than on the newly appeared text makes it disappear.

This works because if the click happened inside (the `.toggle` object, in this case), we call `e.stopPropagation()` for the click event to stop propagating further up towards the entire window.
However if the click occurred somewhere else, it propagates directly to the window and makes `.toggle` disappear.

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/vmFs3/) of it working on jsfiddle.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.test').bind('click', function(e){ 
            $('.toggle').fadeIn(); 
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $('.toggle').bind('click', function(e){ 
            e.stopPropagation(); 
        });
        $(document).bind('click', function(){ 
            $('.toggle').fadeOut(); 
        });
    });
</script>

<a class="test" href="#">test</a>
<div class="toggle">asdasdsa</div>
```

Comment: You don't really have to. It's just a framework for javascript that makes it easier for you to bind functions to events, and to locate objects in the DOM tree (among others). All you have to do to make this example work is to download the jquery js from their website and include it in your html as in the first line of my code.