# Drop down suggestion boxes in SO

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [auto-complete search suggestion drop-down popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176587/auto-complete-search-suggestion-drop-down-popup)

I want to create a functionality similar to autosuggest boxes that pop out when adding tags to questions in stack overflow which appear inside a form field when clicked on them. How is it possible to create an element inside a form field?

I would be thankful if you also direct me to some existing code or plugin so that I can understand by reading the code.

Edit: My question isn't about autocomplete. I was bothered about how to create a rectangular element within the formfield with the autocomplete text inside the box element. Questions on the side dont seem to cover on this issue

Comment: In the sidebar there are several questions answering this matter. For another time, please search or read the suggested answered questions before asking a new question.

Comment: If the question is not about django, remove the django and python tag.

Answer (score 0):

[django-ajax-selects](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects) is very nice.

Answer (score 0):

**TextExt.JS** is a fantastic jQuery plugin that features tagging / autocomplete functionality.
Have a look at http://textextjs.com/ for more information / code.