# Find similar words in array of words

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, search

I googled these days but nothing helps. 
I m not sure now if its possible, so I thought I just aks at stackoverflow.

The situation:
The user can input a word or in a inputbox. When he finishes a function check if the word is in the array of words - easy. Now I wanna write a help, if one letter is missing or the letters are written the wrong way, a message should popout.

What are the keys to search for? 
I tried:

- javascript find string in array
- javascript find similar words in array
- javascript regex similar words
- ... and more

I hope you undestand what i mean, and can give me some hints.

Comment: take a look at the Levenshtein distance here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance
and the implementations here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance

It provides you with a metric for the similarity of words.

Comment: @peshkira that would make a good answer

Comment: **Git: [js-levenshtein](https://github.com/gustf/js-levenshtein)**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Levenshtein distance is a metric for computing the distance between similar words. For each changed, shuffled or missing letter the distance is increased. You can read more here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

and take a reference for the implementation in different languages here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance

I hope that helps and thanks for the comment up votes ;)

Comment: jump to javascript implementation: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://ruby-snippets.heroku.com/string/levenshtein-distance) for an algorithm to check for similarity between words.

Using the code from there, you can use `array.any?{|e| e.similar?(user_input)}`

You may adjust the threshold as required.
Of course, this is Ruby, so you'd have to translate to javascript...

I copied the code from there:

```
class String

  def levenstein(other, ins=2, del=1, sub=1)

    return nil if self.nil? || other.nil?

    dm = []
    dm[0] = (0..self.length).collect { |i| i * ins}
    fill = [0] * (self.length - 1)

    for i in 1..other.length
      dm[i] = [i * del, fill.flatten] 
    end

    for i in 1..other.length
      for j in 1..self.length
        dm[i][j] = [
          dm[i-1][j-1] + (self[i-1] == other[i-1] ? 0 : sub),
          dm[i][j-1] + ins,
          dm[i-1][j] + del
          ].min
      end
    end

    dm[other.length][self.length]
  end

  def similar?(other, thresh = 2)
    self.levenstein(other) < thresh
  end

end

# Tryout
"Foobar".similar?("Fuubar", 3) # => true
```